# Line skipped but works when I step through

Tags: excel, vba

I created this macro and it skips the line:

```
.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 30
```

If I step through the macro it works.

I have tried to add the row at multiple places, I tried adding a delay. Nothing seems to be working.

The macro automates bar graphs for 3 inputs for each row.

```
Sub CreateCharts()
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim SA_Row, erow As Integer
    Dim Graph_Position As Variant

    SA_Row = 5
    Graph_Position = 79.5
    erow = Worksheets("Graphs").UsedRange.Rows.count

    For count = 5 To erow

        Select Case Cells(SA_Row, 6)

        Case Is <> ""

            Set cht = Worksheets("Graphs").ChartObjects.Add(Top:=Graph_Position, Left:=910, Width:=160, Height:=75)

            Set rng1 = Range(Cells(SA_Row, 6), Cells(SA_Row, 7))
            Set rng2 = Union(Cells(SA_Row, 8), rng1)
            cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng2

            With cht.Chart
                .HasAxis(xlValue) = False
                .HasAxis(xlCategory) = False
                .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
                .HasLegend = False
                .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 30
                .FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 204, 226)
                .FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
                .FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(51, 204, 51)
                .ApplyDataLabels
                .PlotArea.Height = 65
                .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
            End With

            SA_Row = SA_Row + 2
            Graph_Position = Graph_Position + 80

        Case Is = ""
            SA_Row = SA_Row + 2
            Graph_Position = Graph_Position + 26

    End Select

    Next count

End Sub
```

DoEvents did not work.

I was unable to add ".ChartGroups(1).Select" due to the object/property does not support his method. I tried to add it both above and on the same row.

Comment: Add `DoEvents()` after that line.

Comment: and qualify all of your Range/Cells calls with a specific worksheet - don't rely on the active sheet.

Comment: There are some things, specifically as I've observed in Excel and PowerPoint charting over the years, which seem to only succeed if you first `Select` the object. This of course goes against the general rule which is to *avoid* relying on `Select` and `Activate`, but there are a few quirky things that seem to need it, when even `DoEvents` or a waiting loop are unreliable. So, if all else fails, try `ChartGroups(1).Select` and then `ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 30`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll go ahead and update the code and see what works. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: The "doevents" did not work unfortunately and I was unable to add ".ChartGroups(1).Select" due to that the object/property does not support his method (when I tried added it both above and on the same row). Any suggestions?:/ I'm new to programming so its probable that I'm overlooking something here